# How to handle big numbers in Haxe?

Tags: haxe, bignum

Is there a library/class/datatype to handle big numbers in Haxe and is also platform independant ?

what i'm trying to do is an incremental game (like clicker heroes) but I'm stuck to the 32bit integer limit.

I found one or two classes whil googling but they are either platform/language dependant (like java math) or not maintained anymore since ages.

Thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of today, there are not that many implementations in Haxe but i know of one in the thx lib :

See https://github.com/fponticelli/thx.core

Comment: thanks, that is exectly what I was looking for, I'm still running into some bugs/errors but that's part of the learning curve